# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent React Native

Tags: android, react-native

`I am using react native 0.69.2 .

I have one activity in my project and i want to make it **android:exported='false'** but while building i get an error "**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent**".`

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>`
```

`Is there any way to make the main activity **android:exported='false'** ?`

Comment: I don't think the error is due to the exported="false". Can you update question with the permission you are requesting and getting the issue.

Comment: <permission android:name="com.testpackage.mypermission" android:label="my_permission" android:protectionLevel="normal"></permission>

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent`  whenever you try to launch an Activity that isn't either exported.
You can not set `android:exported=false` to the launcher activity. If you do then your app will not be able to be launched from the app drawer.

for more info check this [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/android-exported)